# Drop Down Menu - Submenu doesnt retract when another clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Drop Down Menu - Submenu doesnt retract when another clicked
Here is my code can anyone help as to what I need to add to make the submenu retract when another submenu is clicked please.

```
function($){
$.fn.dropdowns = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
        toggleWidth: 1221
    }

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    var ww = document.body.clientWidth;

    var addParents = function() {
        $(".nav li a").each(function() {
            if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
                $(this).addClass("parent");
            }
        });
    }

    var adjustMenu = function() {
        if (ww < options.toggleWidth) {
            $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "inline-block");
            if (!$(".toggleMenu").hasClass("active")) {
                $(".nav").hide();
            } else {
                $(".nav").show();
            }
            $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');

            $(".nav li a.parent").unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
                // must be attached to anchor element to prevent bubbling
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent("li").toggleClass("hover");
            });
        } 
        else if (ww >= options.toggleWidth) {
            $(".toggleMenu").css("display", "none");

            $(".nav").show();
            $(".nav li").removeClass("hover");
            $(".nav li a").unbind('click');
            $(".nav li").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
                // must be attached to li so that mouseleave is not triggered when hover over submenu
                $(this).toggleClass('hover');
            });
        }
    }

    return this.each(function() {
        $(".toggleMenu").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            $(this).next(".nav").toggle();
            adjustMenu();
        });
        adjustMenu();
        addParents();
        $(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
            ww = document.body.clientWidth;
            adjustMenu();
        });
    });

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated I can supply html and css

Comment: Just to add this is on mobile

Comment: drop a jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry I am very new to js can you explain please?

Comment: you don't know how to drop a jsfiddle? i will drop you the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ you drop the code in it, get it?